# Preventing an array from recalculating

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple Computed Property on one of my Ember Data models. It's a `question` that hasMany `answers`, and answers have an ordering.

Here's the CP:

```
// models/question.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  orderedAnswers: function() {
    return this.get('answers').sortBy('position');
  }.property('answers.@each.position')
});
```

Elsewhere in my app, I update a property on one of these `answers`, and this CP gets triggered and recalculated. This causes reflows in my app and causes me to lose app state.

Any ideas why this is happening? The positions aren't changing, I placed a debugger in the CP and verified that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually the response from my Pretender server. I was responding with a status code of 200 and some data, and that caused Ember Data to invalidate the object in its identity map.

To prevent this, either return no data, or return a status code of 204.